# New Azure user has no active subscriptions

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am a long time AWS user but need to trial something on MS Azure.

I have created a Free Trial subscription.

I then created a Namespace in the Default Directory, and added the user to that. I want this user to be able to use Azure services as a Global Administrator.

When I login as that user, I get a splash that says the user has no active subscriptions.

Is this something to do with the Free Trial (ie it only allows one user)?

I can see that "Rights Management" is disabled in the Default Directory, and when I try to enable it, I am told

"Cannot detect Rights Management (RMS) support for Default Directory. To use RMS with this tenant, you must have a subscription that supports RMS."

Answer (score 1):

Global Administrators is a term used in Azure Active Directory only.  This role has no permission on the subscription itself.

You will have to add the user to the subscription explicitly as long as the subscription is AAD backed.

See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to CtrlDot for the lead. The link in that answer might as well be in arabic if you are not familiar with Active Directory and Microsoft authentication regime, which must new Azure users will not be.

I was able to piece this together from the following link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/

Steps:

1. Create the user in the Default Directory (Active Directory) with whatever permission you want
2. Follow the steps in the link above to create a new subscription user, which you can then choose from the list of users in the Active Directory
3. Log out of *everything* and then try to login at https://portal.azure.com as the new user

One thing that is very disconcerting about using the Azure portal when you are familiar with AWS is the frequency with which is spawns new browser windows. As per normal with Microsoft, in trying to make this product idiot-proof, they've made it a horrible experience for people who understand how to work a computer.

Comment: Can't argue with your last comment :)